# How to make API calls in Blazor WebAssembly faster?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I started developing an app in Blazor WebAssembly some days ago (moving an app from Blazor Server) and realized the data load is a bit slow since takes some milliseconds to load after the page is ready (read below) so I was wondering if there is any way to improve API calls so they do not take as long to return the data. I think the code could use some improvements in deserialization. For example the following code is used to display the data inside the square in the home page which means I need an API call to get the data from the DB.

[image]

This is how it looks like before the data is loaded ("hola" is a temporary placeholder value):

[image]

Controller located in the server to get the data from the DB through Entity Framework Core:

```
[HttpGet("FitxatgesAvui/{idTreballador}")]
public IEnumerable<MovimentRed> GetFitxatgesAvui(Guid idTreballador)
{
            return AppDbContext.Fitxatges
                    .Where(f => f.IdTreballador == idTreballador && f.HoraEntradaAjustada.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(m => new MovimentRed()
                    {
                        IdFitxatge = m.IdFitxatge,
                        HoraEntradaAjustada = m.HoraEntradaAjustada,
                        HoraSortidaAjustada = m.HoraSortidaAjustada
                    })
                    .ToList();
}
```

API call located in the page backend (client):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
FitxatgesAvui = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MovimentRed[]>("/Fitxatge/FitxatgesAvui/" + IdTreballador);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = dt2 - dt1;
Console.WriteLine((int)span.TotalMilliseconds);
```

I thought about using another JSON deserialization library other than `System.Text.Json` such as `Newtonsoft.Json` but according to this [page](https://inspiration.nlogic.ca/en/a-comparison-of-newtonsoft.json-and-system.text.json) the native library is faster.

**Extra information**

- The DB (MariaDB) is in the same network as the app (both client and
  server).
- MovimentRed is a DTO class.

  public class MovimentRed
  {
  public Guid IdFitxatge { get; set; }
  public DateTime? HoraEntradaAjustada { get; set; }
  public DateTime? HoraSortidaAjustada { get; set; }
  }

**Measurements**

- API call from the example: around 5 ms
- "Bytes-only" call: around 5 ms
- Database query: around 3 ms
- API call through Postman: around 10 ms
- Bytes: 418 B (280 B size)

[image]

If need more information do not hesitate to ask. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this. You've essentially said "I make an API call and if feels like it's a bit slow". We need measurements; you have to isolate the slow part, show us what it's doing and then we can suggest something. If at the end of it you say "getting data from the DB takes the 7ms, the DB is in USA and the webserver is in Europe and that can't change" the answer might be "c'est la vie" (but maybe you can put a redis in europe)

Comment: You are right @CaiusJard . I added more information to the post.

Comment: You still haven't provided any meaningful measurements or isolations. You are saying that DB is in the same network as the app, but which app? Server or client?. Have you tried masuring the whole HttpClient request on client side? If you want to blame the deserialization - try to download the bare bytes and compare the performance there

Comment: I meant both client and server are hosted on my machine. The DB is not but it is in the same network.
If measuring the Http get request means how long it takes yes, around 140 ms to be exact. Should I compare it with a "bytes only" request then? Appreciated. @Jakoss

Comment: Yes, you should. You should measure every single step before going to performance conclusions

Comment: Also measure the database request - if that is taking 120ms, then you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Added some more info @Jakoss

Comment: @MisterMagoo . Apparently I can't mention more than one user in the same comment

Comment: @Deividgp And what is the response time when done in postman? Or in any other client?

Comment: Also - make sure to measure multiple time and get an average. You have to keep in mind that JIT needs some time to warm up it's caches

Comment: Response time through Postman is around 10 ms. I realized the first requests just right after starting the server take longer but did not take those into account for the measurements. Also, good to know Jit causes this, was wondering why. Furthermore, I am looking into another Http library called Restsharp but seems heavier than the native one. @Jakoss

Comment: `HttpClient` was never a bottleneck in any projects i've worked on, but i guess it's worth a shot in your case. Anyway this seems like some issue with the runtime for webassembly. Maybe consider raising an issue directly to microsoft

Comment: Two more questions: 1. What does the browser network tab show for timing on the api request? 2. How are you measuring in your Blazor code?

Comment: Uhm that's awkward, didn't think of the Network tab to be honest, not really experienced in API development as you may guess (was using the classic DateTime method into milliseconds with an await, not the best idea). Thanks @MisterMagoo. Still don't understand why takes some time to show up though taking into account the requests take 5-10 ms (values updated).

Comment: That's why I asked how you are measuring - can you show us that code?

Comment: Sure, there it is @MisterMagoo

Comment: System improvement in terms of speed and performance is a continuous process but not a one time remedy, some areas might be obvious for improvements, but some will be evident during course of time, so you need to first improve API area which depends on disk reads and network and then can improve UI part. but still you can not guarantee same performance all the time as it dependents on certain areas like network speed, server response etc.

Comment: Ok, so next - can we see the definition of `MovimentRed` and also please measure how much data you are fetching with this call (in Bytes)?

Comment: Done @MisterMagoo . For some reason MovimentRed ignores the code sample format.